# Get the non-empty element using XPATH

Tags: xpath

I have the following XML

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <group>
    <p1></p1>
  </group>
  <group>
    <p1>value1</p1>
  </group>
  <group>
    <p1></p1>
  </group>
</root>
```

is it possible to get the last the node with value? in this case get the value of the second group/p1.

Comment: Post your your xslt or xpath please

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about something like `/root/group/p1[text() and not(../following-sibling::group/p1/text())]`

In other words: get the p1 elements that have text and whose group parents are not followed by group nodes that have non-empty p1 elements.

Comment: I did, it returns one node as intended.

Comment: this one works, i tried it here and it gives me what i want http://www.xpathtester.com/test

Answer (score 74):

This xpath should work as well:

```
//group/p1[string-length(text()) > 0]
```

Comment: It also works with attributes like src //group/p1[string-length(@src) > 0]. Thanks!

Comment: For me this worked, because I had texts with only one backspace inside:
[string-length(text()) > 1]
Thank you a lot @Nora :)

Comment: Amazing tip @Nora

Answer (score 2):

You may also use `[not(node())]` Selector. 
Example: `//group/p1[not(node())]`

Comment: Shouldn't this be the inverse of that?   `//group/p1[node()]`

Answer (score 2):

It actually can be simplified as below:

```
//group/p1[string-length() > 0]    => element text is non-empty
//group/p1[string-length() = 6]    => element text has length 6
```