# How to use XPath to select non-empty paragraph?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, scrapy

The webpages I want to scrape have similar structures. Each has a paragraph which is a question and a paragraph which is an answer. I want to scrape each question and answer and store them in two items

The problem is that on some pages, the question and the answer are respectively `//xxx/p[1]` and `//xxx/p[2]`, but on other pages, the `//xxx/p[1]` is an empty paragraph without any text, which serves as an extra space. For these pages, `//xxx/p[1]` won't give me what I desire.

So is there an XPath expression that can select non-empty paragraphs under one node?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the non-empty element using XPATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031673/get-the-non-empty-element-using-xpath)

Comment: what about `//xxx/p[text()]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's no text at all, you can use

```
//p[.//text()]
```

to select paragraphs with text. If the "empty" paragraphs contain whitespace (e.g. newlines), you have to normalize the whitespace first:

```
//p[normalize-space(.//text())]
```

which can be shortened to

```
//p[normalize-space()]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you define *non-empty* to mean that the paragraph has content of any sort, then the following XPath will be what you want:

```
//xxx/p[node()]
```

This will ***not*** select `<p/>` and `<p></p>` but will select each of the following:

1. `<p>Text</p>`
2. `<p><b>Text</b></p>`
3. `<p><br/></p>`
4. `<p><!-- comment --></p>`

If you are really only concerned about text content, the following XPath will exclude `<p/>` and `<p></p>` along with cases #3 and #4 above:

```
//xxx/p[string(.)]
```

In other words, it'll select only cases #1 and #2, which are the cases where the string value of the paragraph is not empty.