# select for only contain empty elements in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to select `td` element which contains empty in XSLT.

Input:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>AWS</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>ED123</td>
    <td>      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Tried XPath:

```
table/tr/td[text() != ' ']
```

My tried Xpath is not working properly.

As the results `td[2]` and `td[4]` should be selected.

I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use XPath to select non-empty paragraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34596569/how-to-use-xpath-to-select-non-empty-paragraph)

Comment: The question is confusing because none of the `td` elements in the example is empty and it's not clear whether a truly empty `td` should be selected or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
table/tr/td[normalize-space()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
/table/tr/td[not(normalize-space())]
```

to select the elements containing only whitespace or are empty.