# Need help finding first non-empty element in XML using XSLT

Tags: xslt

XML element contains both empty and non-empty values. I need to capture the first non-empty element. I have tried for-each loops with a conditional when/choose or if statements but reading other posts, it seems this should be simple to do using select="" in XSL.

For-each with choose/if conditional statements always returns multiple values when I only want the first non-empty element and its value to be 
returned/assigned to my variable or directly within XSL HTML code.

I have also tried following this example for doing something similar:
[Get the non-empty element using XPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031673/get-the-non-empty-element-using-xpath)

but my variable always returns 'empty'.

Here is a snippet of the XML I am processing with both empty and non-empty element values for ifid:

```
<transaction>

<SurePayDetails>
<Subfield>

<ifid></ifid>

</Subfield>
</SurePayDetails>

<SurePayDetails>
<Subfield>

<ifid></ifid>

</Subfield>
</SurePayDetails>
<SurePayDetails>
<Subfield>

<ifid>0022</ifid>
</Subfield>
</SurePayDetails>

</transaction>
```

I have tried accessing/assigning to a variable the first non-empty
 element using the following:

`<xsl:variable name="auth_code" select="/transaction/SurePayDetails/Subfield/ifid[text()[string-length(.) > 0]][1]"/>`

which as I understand it will select the first ifid element whose length is greater than 0 and `[1]` selects that value.

I am not sure if I am referencing the XML correctly in the above `select=""` because if I traverse the document with the following:

```
`<xsl:for-each select="//ns1:transaction/ns1:SurePayDetails/ns1:Subfield">
.
.
<xsl:variable name="auth_code" select="ns1:ifid"/>`
```

the auth_code is populated with both empty and non-empty values as expected.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following expressions. Because of operator precedence, the first part has to be enclosed in brackets.

```
<xsl:variable name="auth_code"  select="(/transaction/SurePayDetails/Subfield/ifid[normalize-space(text())])[1]" />
```

or shorter

```
<xsl:variable name="auth_code"  select="(//ifid[normalize-space(text())])[1]" />
```

---

EDIT: In a whole template with added namespaces this could look like this: it outputs the first `ns1:ifid` value.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <xsl:value-of select="(/ns1:transaction/ns1:SurePayDetails/ns1:Subfield/ns1:ifid[normalize-space(text())])[1]" />
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for this however, both `select=...` still returns empty in my later 
`<td><tr><xsl:value-of select="$auth_code"/></td></tr>` code. 

This is an XSLT version 1.0 XSL and this is what is at the top of the XSL:

`<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.omnicogroup.com/FPF/namespace" xmlns:ns1="http://www.omnicogroup.com/FPF/namespace" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
`

Comment: Hi - yes, I did:
`<td><tr><xsl:value-of select="$auth_code"/></td></tr>`

Comment: Here is the for-each loop that is able to assign empty/non-empty values to my variable (auth_code) that is getting the value of `<ifid>`:

`<xsl:for-each select="//ns1:transaction/ns1:SurePayDetails/ns1:Subfield"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="string-length($auth_code) > 0">
<xsl:variable name="auth_code" select="ns1:ifid"/>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>`

Comment: I changed the given for-each and updated my answer.

Comment: Correction to my previous code snippet for a working for-each block that captures all non-empty ifid elements:
`<xsl:for-each select="//ns1:transaction/ns1:SurePayDetails/ns1:Subfield">
<xsl:variable name="auth_code" select="ns1:ifid"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="string-length($auth_code) > 0">
<tr><td class="transaction_payment_left" width="364" valign="top" align="left" style="font-size:12px;line-height:18px;">
&#160;&#160;AUTH&#160;<xsl:value-of select="$auth_code"/></td></tr><br/>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
`

Thanks.

Comment: In your question you wrote `I need to capture the first non-empty element.`. Now you are looping over all elements... BTW please add code with an edit to your question and not in comments.

Comment: Glad you found a solution.

Comment: Thank you - seems not referencing in the `select=""` the namespace `ns1:` layout using your last snippet was the issue and now my auth_code variable is getting assigned the first non-empty `<ifid>` element!

This snippet now works:
`<xsl:variable name="auth_code" select="(//ns1:transaction/ns1:SurePayDetails/ns1:Subfield/ns1:ifid[normalize-space(text())])[1]"/>`