# XPath search for existing value

Tags: xpath

I am having an issue where when I create a condition where a value could be present but doesn't exist, im unable to pull the data

For Example I would be wanting to pull all location numbers with valid location names

```
<bookstores>
    <location>
        <name>ABCBooks</name>
        <locationtotals>100</locationtotals>
    </location>
    <location>
         <name>GrandBooks</name>
         <locationtotals>200</locationtotals>
    </location>
    <location>
         <name/>
         <locationtotals>150</locationtotals>
    </location>
</bookstores>
```

This is the logic I have been attempting to use but it does not pull any content
sum(location[name != '']/locationtotals) where i would be expecting a value of 300 but it gets returned as 0, the level I have set to loop through is bookstores.

is there any logic to check if a value exists that i can put in my conditions rather than the [name != '']?

Thank you very much

Comment: Your XML is malformed. `</name>` without an opening tag is not valid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the non-empty element using XPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031673/get-the-non-empty-element-using-xpath)

Comment: @Phil - thank you for spotting that mistake, the xml has been reformatted with the <name/>, but the same issue continues to be the same. what would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

From the question

> "the level I have set to loop through is bookstores"

How are you setting the context and is bookstores really the context of the expression during your execution?

Modifying your expression slightly to account for the context such as:

```
sum(bookstores/location[name != '']/locationtotals)
```

or

```
sum(//location[name != '']/locationtotals)
```

gives the result you are looking for.

Comment: So the method we are using the XPath language is through EText, where a staring level can be identified (bookstores) and etext will know that if we use the example expression it will iterate through all possible levels of <location> until the </bookstores> is reached, the main issue is that is only </name> is present for any given <location> it will zero out the entire sum

Comment: Are you saying that this XML is always going to be malformed with that `</name>`?  If you are trying to get correct results with malformed XML I am not sure how we can help you.

Comment: is it an non-standard practice to have data extracted into XML format to have this kind of </name> format? or aske din another way, should all of my <name> values be structured like <name></name> even if there is a null value in it?

Comment: @Nathan.Parry The answer is correct; you can have an element with a null value, but it has to be `<name/>`, not `</name>`.

Comment: It's not a null value: you need to be precise when talking about these things. It's an element that has no child text nodes (or any child nodes of any kind, in fact), and whose string value is a zero-length string. Testing either `name[.='']` or `name[.!='']` should work as expected, because you're testing the string value of the element. Testing `name[text()='']` gives a result you might not expect, because there is no text node to be tested.

Comment: Michael - is your suggestion a working solution to check if that element has any value populating it?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for all the help!
We were able to solve the issue because in my actual xml file I was calling the condition at the incorrect level, the levels had almost identical names and the level i was calling was the incorrect one.
This issue is cleared even thought this problem was false positive.